# how to copy a string that appears on tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a password generator script that works fine, problem is, i present the password in the GUI in a label and it doesn't give me the option to copy it so i can put the password where i want it, how can i print the password to the GUI so i can copy it after, is there a better way than label?
I am using the function

```
tk.Label(root,text=k).grid(row=1)
```

k being the variable where the password is stored
Alternately if there is some python function that enables me to just straight up copy the contents of k to the clipboard that might be even better, thanks

Comment: change text to textvariable

Comment: it doesnt print anything anymore

Comment: You could call the universal widget method `clipboard_clear()` followed by a `clipboard.append(k)` to copy the contents of variable `k` to the clipboard. Here's some [documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20181025095013id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) about the universal widget methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use an `Entry` widget with the state set to `"readonly"`.

Example:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root)
entry.pack(side="top", padx=20, pady=20)

# insert the password
entry.insert(0, "SuperSecretPassw0rd!")

# configure the entry to readonly
entry.configure(state="readonly")

root.mainloop()
```

You can also automatically add it to the clipboard with the `clipboard_clear` and `clipboard_append` methods:

```
root.clipboard_clear()
root.clipboard_append(entry.get())
```

Comment: If the text is in an `Entry` widget, does the program need to explicitly select its entire contents to get it copied to the clipboard?

Comment: it just prints a greyed out entry box, it doesnt print the password

Comment: @Letho123: you have to insert the password into the entry widget. I've updated my answer with an example

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to get or set a value in a TK gui?  Instead of using a `Label`, I would use an `Entry`, and I would use one of the TK variable classes (such as StringVar) for `k`, which have `get` and `set` methods

here's a example of a script I use to get and set text values in a TK widget:

```
frame = tk.Frame(master)
frame.pack()
filepath = tk.StringVar()
filepath.set("/Volumes/data/data/test_data/")        
fileentry = tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=filepath, width=125)
fileentry.pack()

if something:
    a = filepath.get()
```

reference to TK variable classes: https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm